# Drag and Drop position relative to destination container

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a drag and drop solution for a map. I have all the events firing properly, and am able to get a location when I drop the object. The issue I have is the location is based on the overall position of the mouse, I need it to be the relative position of the container catching the object.

If the map is larger than the screen, or starts above the visible area, I need to know where on the map, not where on the screen the drop is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Current script:

```
    function dropInSiteMap(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('<%=hf_X.ClientID %>').value = ev.x;
        document.getElementById('<%=hf_Y.ClientID %>').value = ev.y;
    }
```

Comment: I think it would help a lot of people if your example was a little more thorough. In general, `.offsetTop` will give the offset relative to the element's parent.

Comment: @Djave I'm confused as to what isn't thorough. I have an image (map), and things I need to move around the map. I need to store the X/Y of the things based on the map, not the screen. ev.x gives me the x of the cursor, not relative to the map. 

Say the map starts at x=-50, and the cursor is on X=25 on the screen, i need to return the value 75 not 25.

Your suggestion of .offestTop, is that ev.offsetTop in the script? ev being the object moving, i wouldn't think that would work.

Comment: @Djave After taking a look at what you said and what I'm doing, I tried this:

    document.getElementById('<%=hf_Y.ClientID %>').value = ev.y - document.getElementById('<%=img_Sitemap.ClientID %>').offsetTop;

Works as long as my map starts on the screen, however if my map starts off the screen, my result is a negative number (I would assume subtracting a negative would get me addition, but it's not?) Any suggestions outside of storing both  cursor X/Y, and imageoffset X/Y and writing my own intelligent math in the code behind?

Comment: Hey @KnightsOfTheRoun I meant it would be helpful to know its an image, not a map (like a Google map), what drag and drop library are you using (if you are using one). Things like that are useful when you try and debug stuff like this that isn't your code. Usually I like to create a codepen or jsfiddle to share on stackoverflow. If its "off the screen" because you have scrolled down, you could minus `window.scrollTop` from number you get back.

Comment: @Djave My apologies, I thought saying it was a map implied it was an image. 

Looking into the offset, I realize it's not the value I need, as it's based on the page, not the current display and window.

I'll look into window for it's values. 

I appreciate all the help, sometimes you need someone to point out the glaringly obvious.

Comment: Great, happy to help!

Comment: @Djave Got it! Essentially:  ev.x + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft - document.getElementById('<%=img_Sitemap.ClientID %>').offsetLeft)